# Devexpress AspxScheduler displays the current time line across calendar (colour amber-ish)

Tags: devexpress

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Set the OptionsBehavior.[ShowTimeMarker](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxSchedulerASPxSchedulerOptionsBehavior_ShowTimeMarkertopic) property to False to hide this line..